# Not able to pass object in graphql mutation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, graph, graphql-js

Can anyone tell me how to pass array of object in graphql mutation from react js side.I tried passing the object in react but getting error of not same type.

```
[input type][1]
[from api side][2]
[declaring the object][3]
[passing object in mutation][4]
[error i'm facing][5]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufVtA.png 
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQt5m.png 
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnxLM.png 
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JCHf.png 
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BonPE.png
```

Comment: please provide the code and what error you are getting

Comment: HI please find the images i added

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect a proper problem description from you here; just holding up images is not considered one.

Answer (score 1):

What i understood from your problem is that, You want to pass array of objects as argument to the mutation. It can be done easily.

First define a input in the schema,as below. It has the value name as string. You  can add whatever you want.  This structure will be used for passing value as argument.

```
    input Product {
        name: String
    }
```

The above created input will be passed as a array as given below.

```
    type RootMutation{
        createProduct(product: [Product]): String
    }
```

You will get the data in the resolver

```
createProduct: (args)=>{
// You will get the value in this 'args'
// Do Whatever you want
}
```

The input is given as follow

```
createProduct(product:[{name:"has"}])
```